# Last used cell in excel is so large excel crashes when trying to delete excess columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I have a worksheet where the last used cell is said to be cells(1048381,BH). I know I'm supposed to delete all rows (and columns, but less relevant in this particular case as all columns through BH are actually be used) until the final row, but the final row is such a large number that excel (64-bit) crashes when I go to fix the problem. Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried taking the delete in smaller bites, such as 100 or 1,000 rows at a time?  Although, I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm supposed to delete all rows ... until the final row". This is tagged as VBA, so can you post the code that is crashing?

Comment: If your code crashes excel, it would be good to post that code.  Have you considered just deleting the sheet instead?

Comment: If Excel still crashes after you try to delete a few lines (per Rey Juna's suggestion), the file may be corrupted. The best thing to do at that point is to copy the cells (*not* the sheet) into a new Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to delete the rows between the last valid row of data and a rogue last cell. Using Home, Editing, Clear, Clear All is sufficient and is much less calculation intensive.

Here is some code that performs the same action on a rogue populated cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub resetRogueRow()

    Dim lr As Long, nr As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet2")

        lr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.Cells(1), _
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Row
        nr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.Cells(lr, 1), _
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Row

        .Cells(nr + 1, "A").Resize(lr - nr, 1).EntireColumn.Clear

    End With
End Sub
```